# fighters come sailing

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the exact meaning of the words in bold in the following passage? It is from the book “Persian Gulf Command” by Ashley Jackson, p. 97.

‘After this,’ wrote Freya Stark, ‘in a sort of golden mist of sunset our bombers and fighters **came sailing: they came in troops and societies.**

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fighters** = attack aircraft

**Sailing** is often used figuratively to mean travelling at high speed: e.g. "Bullets went sailing over the heads of the villagers."

Then there is more figurative language:

they came **in troops** = they came in large numbers of similar aircraft

and **societies**. = they came in [large] groups of different aircraft.

Comment: Yes, at high speed and smoothly, as a boat sails smoothly.